# How to further debug server error 'Named export not found'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I'm completely stuck on how to fix this server error.

```
SyntaxError: Named export 'useId' not found. The requested module 'react' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from 'react';
const { useContext, useId, useEffect } = pkg;

file:///Users/sashabb/Documents/apps/two-five-footwear/node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/use-presence.mjs (1)
```

I initially though it might be a node dep issue so I ran `--legacy-peer-deps` to no avail.

`useId` does not exist in repo when searched

Is this specifically an issue with framer motion package? any advice would be much appreciated